# What does structured estimator mean?

Tags: finance, quantitative

I'm reading Ledoit&Wolf's paper "Honey, I shrunk the sample covariance matrix" and it is mentioned a lot of time, but I don't understand what it means. I thought that probably referred to estimation instability, but I'm not sure. Help.

Comment: A structured estimator is one that isn't super flexible and has a lot of prior structure. For example, in the case of Ledoit and wolf, the diagonal covariance matrix is very structured, in that it assumes there is no correlation between returns of assets in the portfolio.

Comment: Of course it is a relative/comparative term. For example linear regression is very structured relative to something like an artificial neural network.

Comment: @rubikscube09 thanks, But I think that in Ledoit&Wolf they assume a constant correlation. So correct If I'm wrong: in this contest "structured estimator" means an estimator which has some pre-fixed characteristics?

Comment: Yes, the structured esimator will produce an estimate that has some pre-fixed characteristics (i.e. some structure).